# JAVA: Resetting delimiter after string to use .nextDouble

Tags: java, delimiter

NOTE: Do not want the answer to this problem, as I want to teach myself, but I am stuck and would like advice as to what to do.

So for practice, I have to read an input file and echo it.

The practice problem is to create a ATM transaction, one line of the input file reads:
    Stacy Jones, 300 D 100

I have to output it as:

```
name
current balance
action (D means deposit)
transaction amount
```

I currently have the name, and to get the current balance I changed the delimiter to end the line at the comma, however my problem is that there is still white space before current balance (i.e. 300)

Here is my code:

```
try {
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("src/transactions.txt");
    fileIn = new Scanner(stream);

    fileIn.useDelimiter(",");
    name = fileIn.next();
    System.out.println("Customer Name: " + name);
    fileIn.reset();
    balance = fileIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("Checking balance before transaction: %.2f", balance);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Transactions cannot be found");
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:857)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2404)
at MP3.main(MP3.java:30)
```

Comment: `Catch` the *exception* and print the input you're trying to `nextDouble` and you'll understand the problem.

Comment: Caught the exception and I System.out.println(fileIn) and it gave me this:
    delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your input. When you do `fileIn.nextDouble()` you are expecting a double. What you are getting from the file is actually the String `' 300'`, so with a space in front.
This cannot be converted to a double by Scanner.

This should point you already in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can re deli-mate  the second token by space as

```
 FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("src/transactions.txt");
        fileIn = new Scanner(stream);
        fileIn.useDelimiter(",");
        name = fileIn.next();
        System.out.println("Customer Name: " + name);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fileIn.next());
        s.useDelimiter(" ");
        balance = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Checking balance before transaction: %.2f %n", balance);
        System.out.println("Action: "+s.next());
        System.out.println("Transaction amount: "+s.nextDouble());
        fileIn.reset();
```